How to add menu to a region when viewing a node revision?
We have a layout with the menu in a left 'sidebar' region. The menu opens to the correct parent item when browsing a node as it should.
When browsing the latest (or any) revision of the node, the menu doesn't appear - most probably because the new path with the revision in it does not match any menu items.
Its actually very important to the workflow and QA of this site that the menu is located correctly and with the correct active item highlighted when browsing the revision.
What I'd like to do is load the menu programatically and put it into this sidebar with the correct active item etc. I feel I need to do this programatically because of the difference in URI.
Back in the D7 days you could simply set the active item with a call to 'menu_set_active'.
Whats the best option here?

Is the original change record from 2014 about replacing that function in Drupal 8 still helpful here? https://www.drupal.org/node/2302069

That was helpful, thanks @monalisa. I dont know how I missed that in all my searching.
